# How to get the names of the DbSet properties included in an Entity Framework query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

I have the following `DbSet` properties defined in my `DbContext` class:

```
public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

Each *employee* belongs to a *company*, and each *company* has some *products*. I can write the following queries using Entity Framework:

```
IQueryable<Employee> query1 = context.Employees.Where(e => e.Id == 1);
IQueryable<Employee> query2 = context.Employees.Where(e => e.Id == 1).Include(x => x.Company);
IQueryable<Employee> query3 = context.Employees.Where(e => e.Id == 1).Include(x => x.Company).ThenInclude(x => x.Products);
```

Given a query, I want to get a list of the names of the `DbSet` properties that are included in it. For example, for `query2`, I want to get "Employees" and "Companies" as the output.

I tried to inspect the `Expression` property of the query, and cast it to a `MethodCallExpression`. Then I looked at the *Arguments* property, which contains a *navigation property expression*. However, I don't see a direct way to get the name of the *DbSet* property from the navigation property expression, except by inferring it from the type of the navigation property (e.g., Company => Companies).

Is there a more reliable way to get the names of the DbSet properties included in an Entity Framework query?

Comment: Why exactly do you want that?

Comment: *I don't see a direct way to get the name of the DbSet property from the navigation property expression* - because EF do not use `DbContext` properties for query building and do not store such information. They exist only for сonvenience of developer. IOW it is possible to have `DbContext` without these properties, but still working.

Comment: @GuruStron I have two intentions in mind. First diagnostics logging of queries including navigation properties by parameters. The second one is for caching - from DbSet properties I derive tables and I can track changes in DB whether the chache is still valid.

Comment: _"The second one is for caching - from DbSet properties I derive tables and I can track changes in DB whether the chache is still valid."_ - I would argue that it would be better to use change tracker for such things. As for logging it is hard to tell.